# Increasing scope of powershell session variable in exec.Command() while in remote connection

Tags: powershell, go, stdout, invoke-command

I am trying to use Powershell remotely through an application written in Go, but am unable to store the session variable returned on calling the New-PSSession command.

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "os/exec"
)

type PowerShell struct {
        powerShell string
}

func New() *PowerShell {
        ps, _ := exec.LookPath("powershell.exe")
        return &PowerShell{
                powerShell: ps,
        }
}

func (p *PowerShell) Execute(args ...string) (stdOut string, stdErr string, err error) {
        cmd := exec.Command(p.powerShell, args...)

        var stdout bytes.Buffer
        var stderr bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &stdout
        cmd.Stderr = &stderr

        err = cmd.Run()
        stdOut, stdErr = stdout.String(), stderr.String()
        return
}

func main() {
        posh := New()

        stdout, stderr, err := posh.Execute("$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName url.test.com")

        fmt.Println(stdout)
        fmt.Println(stderr)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }

        stdout, stderr, err = posh.Execute("Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {New-Item -type file d:\\golang_test_api\\blah.txt}")

        fmt.Println(stdout)
        fmt.Println(stderr)

        if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
        }
}
```

While chaining these commands via a semi-colon works, I need a solution that enables me to increase the scope for the $session variable.
I get this error, for reference:

```
Invoke-Command : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Session'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:25
+ Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {New-Item -type file d: ...
+                         ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: I believe your problem is that whenever you're using posh.Execute it's creating new shell, so you create `$session` on the first run, but it's not available during second run, because this is completely new shell. Maybe pipe would help you, https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.StdinPipe.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. just to be on the safe side I'm now calling on a powershell script which does this. Much more convenient.